# Combine a SELECT and Two UPDATES?

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

```
$query = "SELECT loved FROM users WHERE uid=:quitter";
$query = "UPDATE users SET status='0', loved=NULL, beloved_count='0' WHERE uid=:deceased";
$query = "UPDATE users SET beloved_count=beloved_count-1 WHERE uid=:lover";
```

Because it might not be clear from my code, here's what's happening:
User 123 quits.
I need to
1) Find out who 123 "loved"
2) Update 123's row (set status='0', etc.)
3) Update the "loved" user's row and reduce the "beloved_count" by 1

This all takes place within one table.  Can this happen with one query?  Ideally, I'd like to do it with one query, but even two would be better than where I'm at with 3 separate queries.

I've looked at `JOIN`s, but it simply isn't clear to me since I've never used them before.  I've seen examples of query combinations, but nothing that mirrors this.  I'm using PHP 5.4 and PDO.

---

Something like:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET status='0', loved=NULL, beloved_count='0' WHERE uid=:deceased;  
    UPDATE users SET beloved_count=beloved_count-1 WHERE uid=:lover;";
```

Comment: the two updates are changing different data based on different conditions. you'd be better off doing two queries rather than trying to come up with a huge tangled monstrosity.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was possible, with certain databases and extensions, to have a value returned from an update.  That probably is inapplicable here, huh?

Comment: Agree with Marc B - as an academic exercise, its *possible* to merge the updates and even to carry out the updates as side-effects of the select - but it's not a good idea to do this in practice. (and no, its not possible in SQL for UPDATE to return data).

Comment: no. updates do not return any data, except some metadata, e.g. mysql's "affected rows". you can use a select subquery in an update, e.g. `UPDATE sometable SET somefield=(SELECT ... FROM othertable)`, but that's not what you want. you'd still be effectively running 3+ queries, and making for hideously ugly unmaintainable queries. keep it simple and just do the three queries. they're simple, and the overhead will be minimal.

Comment: OK.

But it is possible to combine my `UPDATE`s for greater efficiency?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but like I said, **UGLY**: `update users SET beloved_count=CASE WHEN uid:=lover THEN beloved_count-1 ELSE beloved_count END, status=CASE WHEN uid:=deceased THEN 0 ELSE status END, blah blah blah.`. You will just be shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Can you only love one person?  What is the contents of the `loved` column?

Comment: Yes, `loved` is a single userid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?  Essentially you are joining quitting user to all the users he loved.

```
UPDATE 
    users AS u1, 
    users AS u2 
SET 
    u1.status='0',
    u1.loved=NULL,
    u1.beloved_count='0',
    u2.beloved_count=u2.beloved_count-1
WHERE 
    u1.uid=:quitter
    AND u1.loved=u2.uid;
```